# Given token is not authorized, Need a python code to verify access into a sharepoint Folder

Tags: python, sharepoint, python-requests, http-status-code-401

I developed the following python code below.

On the other hand, in azure, I created a new app where I got the client Id and tenant ID and to later on, I gave the API permission (check picture):

[image]

as well as the certificate and secrets by (check picture):

[image]

The result I get from the below code is

```
Access token obtained: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ii1LSTNROW5OUjdiUm9meG1lWm9YcWJIWkdldyIsImtpZCI6Ii1LSTNROW5OUjd...... (an extended token)
Authorization failed, status code: 401
```

So, the code is giving me the token but this is unable to be verified when it goes to the sharepoint. I tried everything but nothing works, I gave up.

I wish you have a solution or another way to verify my account to the specific sharepoint folder.

The folder where I need to check my access is in this one : "https://vestas.sharepoint.com/sites/DEP-TurbineEngineering-VAME/Shared Documents/General/Files for BI"

The code is :

```py
import requests

#replace the following with your own values 
client_id = "12345" 
client_secret = "aabbccc" 
tenant_id = "12345aabbcc" 
resource = "https://vestas.sharepoint.com/"

#get the access token 
auth_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token" data = { 
"client_id": client_id, "client_secret": client_secret, "resource": resource, "grant_type": "client_credentials",
}

response = requests.post(auth_url, data=data) 
if response.status_code == 200: 
auth_response = response.json() 
access_token = auth_response["access_token"] 
print("Access token obtained:", access_token) 

else: 
print("Failed to obtain access token, status code:", response.status_code)

#Replace the placeholder with the actual SharePoint API endpoint api_endpoint = "https://vestas.sharepoint.com/sites/DEP-TurbineEngineering-VAME/Shared Documents/General/Files for BI"

headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token, "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }

response = requests.get(api_endpoint, headers=headers)

#Check if the request was successful 
if response.status_code == 200: 
data = response.json() 
print("Authorization successful")

#Do something with the data obtained from the API 
else: 
print("Authorization failed, status code:", response.status_code)
```